# Remove unnecessary url from scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request



class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    start_urls = ['https://www.ifep.ro/justice/lawyers/lawyerspanel.aspx']
    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 1,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1,
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36'
        }
    
    
    
    def parse(self, response):
        books = response.xpath("//div[@class='list-group']//@href").extract()
        for book in books:
            url = response.urljoin(book)
            print(url)
```

I want to remove these unnecessary url from the link the website is https://www.ifep.ro/justice/lawyers/lawyerspanel.aspx

```
http://www.unbr.ro
http://www.inppa.ro
http://www.uniuneanotarilor.ro/
http://www.caav.ro
http://www.executori.ro/
http://www.csm1909.ro
http://www.inm-lex.ro
http://www.just.ro
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to filter out any of the URLs with those domains or do you want to just get everything after the domain in the URL?

Comment: I add the image see these

Comment: you could just check `if 'ifep.ro' in book:` then you can do `url = response.urljoin(book)  print(url)`

Comment: I apply these condition but not give any url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply `endswith` method  along with `continue` keyword to remove the desired urls

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    start_urls = ['https://www.ifep.ro/justice/lawyers/lawyerspanel.aspx']
    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 1,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1,
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36'
        }
    
    
    
    def parse(self, response):
        books = response.xpath("//div[@class='list-group']//@href").extract()
        for book in books:
            url = response.urljoin(book)
            if url.endswith('.ro') or url.endswith('.ro/'):
                continue
            print(url)
```

**Output:**

```
https://www.ifep.ro/justice/lawyers/LawyerFile.aspx?RecordId=1091&Signature=378270
https://www.ifep.ro/justice/lawyers/LawyerFile.aspx?RecordId=159077&Signature=378270
https://www.ifep.ro/justice/lawyers/LawyerFile.aspx?RecordId=159076&Signature=378270
https://www.ifep.ro/justice/lawyers/LawyerFile.aspx?RecordId=159075&Signature=378270
https://www.ifep.ro/justice/lawyers/LawyerFile.aspx?RecordId=159021&Signature=378270
https://www.ifep.ro/justice/lawyers/LawyerFile.aspx?RecordId=159020&Signature=378270
https://www.ifep.ro/justice/lawyers/LawyerFile.aspx?RecordId=159019&Signature=378270
https://www.ifep.ro/justice/lawyers/LawyerFile.aspx?RecordId=159018&Signature=378270
https://www.ifep.ro/justice/lawyers/LawyerFile.aspx?RecordId=21846&Signature=378270
https://www.ifep.ro/justice/lawyers/LawyerFile.aspx?RecordId=165927&Signature=378270
https://www.ifep.ro/justice/lawyers/LawyerFile.aspx?RecordId=83465&Signature=378270
https://www.ifep.ro/justice/lawyers/LawyerFile.aspx?RecordId=47724&Signature=378270
https://www.ifep.ro/justice/lawyers/LawyerFile.aspx?RecordId=32097&Signature=378270
https://www.ifep.ro/justice/lawyers/LawyerFile.aspx?RecordId=29573&Signature=378270
https://www.ifep.ro/justice/lawyers/LawyerFile.aspx?RecordId=19880&Signature=378270
```

Comment: I have  another question can you answer it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72672087/scrape-multiple-pages-who-url-remain-same-in-pagination