# Data are overwrite in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

When I make the csv file data are overwrite in csv file If there is any solution provide me the link of the page is https://www.aeafa.es/asociados.php?provinput=&_pagi_pg=1 have already searched for an answer here and spent a long time on google, but nothing... I've already tried opening the file with 'w' instead of 'r' or 'a' but I still can't get my code to

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

headers ={
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36'
}
for page in range(1,3): 
    r =requests.get('https://www.aeafa.es/asociados.php?provinput=&_pagi_pg={page}'.format(page=page),
    headers=headers) 
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    tag=soup.find_all('div',class_='col-md-8 col-sm-8')
    temp=[]
    for pro in tag:
        data=[tup.text for tup in pro.find_all('p')]
      
        Dirección=data[2]
        Dirección=Dirección[12:]
        
    
        Población=data[3]
        Población=Población[14:]

    

        Provincia=data[4]
        Provincia=Provincia[14:] 

    
        Teléfono=data[5]
        Teléfono="+" + Teléfono[11:].replace('.', "")
        


        Email=data[6]
        Email=Email[10:]
        
        
        

        temp.append([Dirección,Provincia,Población,Teléfono, Email])
    df=pd.DataFrame(temp,columns=["Dirección","Provincia","Población","Teléfono","Email"])
    df.to_csv('samp.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put the list `temp` outside of the for-loop. Then, create the dataframe after all the loops finish:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36"
}

temp = []

for page in range(1, 3):
    r = requests.get(
        "https://www.aeafa.es/asociados.php?provinput=&_pagi_pg={page}".format(
            page=page
        ),
        headers=headers,
    )
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
    tag = soup.find_all("div", class_="col-md-8 col-sm-8")
    for pro in tag:
        data = [tup.text for tup in pro.find_all("p")]

        Dirección = data[2]
        Dirección = Dirección[12:]

        Población = data[3]
        Población = Población[14:]

        Provincia = data[4]
        Provincia = Provincia[14:]

        Teléfono = data[5]
        Teléfono = "+" + Teléfono[11:].replace(".", "")

        Email = data[6]
        Email = Email[10:]

        temp.append([Dirección, Provincia, Población, Teléfono, Email])

df = pd.DataFrame(
    temp, columns=["Dirección", "Provincia", "Población", "Teléfono", "Email"]
)
df.to_csv("samp.csv")

print(len(df))
```

Prints:

```
98
```

---

Screenshot from LibreOffice:

[image]

Comment: Brother no one answer these question can you answer it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72672087/scrape-multiple-pages-who-url-remain-same-in-pagination

Comment: I think  you can provide us solution of these problem

Comment: If you answer it I am very thankful to you

Comment: can you answer it?